# How to Summarize all records with unique Material / plant codes into a single record based on Material

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single table in SQL Server with Material, Plant combinations with inventory qty's and values. This is a staging table for data coming in form the source system. I need to aggregate all these records with the same Material number but different plants into a single record based on Material Number with averaged qty's and values.

This is the Table I am working with.

[image]

I have tried many different SQL statements with this one being the closest to working. Note, The SQL prompt on material in the Where clause is there just to allow me to look at different Materials without copy pasting into the SQL statement.

```
SELECT
  material
 ,plant
 ,AVG(unrestricted) AS Unrestricted
 ,AVG(valueunrestricted) AS valUnrestricted
 ,SUM(ValueUnrestricted / unrestricted) AS UnitValue
FROM
  IBSCM01.stage.MB52
WHERE
  unrestricted IS NOT NULL AND
  unrestricted > 0 AND
  material = :material
GROUP BY
  material
 ,plant
 ,unrestricted
 ,valueunrestricted;
```

This is the output

[image]

What I am looking for is to output a single record based on Material that was aggregated across all plants. If just Group by Material it throws the following error.

> Column 'IBSCM01.stage.MB52.Plant' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: what happens if you just `GROUP BY material`

Comment: I get the following for each field not in the group by clause.  Column 'IBSCM01.stage.MB52.Plant' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Ok, So I removed Plant from the Select and it might be working. I need to go back and do some math, but you may have provided that second set of eyes

Comment: grouping by one field is valid in mysql, not in sql-server.. the 2 tags had me confused..

Comment: Thanks, I did not mean to include anything but SQL Server. Getting used to SQL Server after having been on MySQL for some time.

Comment: I'm confused because the error is telling you what's wrong, as I'm sure you know.  You can't have the GROUP BY without a the column from the SELECT unless it is an aggregate function.

Each plant you listed is one type of plant, so when you group it, you get one group for each plant.

What you want is to have is, "output a single record based on Material that was aggregated across all plants."  So I do not fully understand what you are asking for.  Can you list an expected outcome?  Do you want a count of Material used for X number of plants?

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a HAVING clause with a COUNT of DISTINCT values?

```
SELECT
  material
 ,plant
 ,AVG(unrestricted) AS Unrestricted
 ,AVG(valueunrestricted) AS valUnrestricted
 ,SUM(ValueUnrestricted / unrestricted) AS UnitValue
FROM
  IBSCM01.stage.MB52
WHERE
  unrestricted IS NOT NULL AND
  unrestricted > 0 AND
  material = :material
GROUP BY
  material
 ,plant
 ,unrestricted
 ,valueunrestricted
HAVING count(Distinct(material))>=1
```

I'm confused because the error is telling you what's wrong, as I'm sure you know.  You can't have the GROUP BY without a the column from the SELECT unless it is an aggregate function.

Each plant you listed is one type of plant, so when you group it, you get one group for each plant.

What you want is to have is, "output a single record based on Material that was aggregated across all plants."  So I do not fully understand what you are asking for.

If you do COUNT(plant) you do not have to put the plant column in the GROUP BY.  This will give you the Material and a number.

Comment: This did not work.. as long as Plant is in the Group By it will not aggregate up to the Material. If I remove Plant from the Select and Group By it works fine. Thanks

Comment: I am confused.  Why do you have to have plant in the select?

Comment: I don't have to have Plant int the select, I removed it. What I was saying is that the having Clause has no affect on the output even after removing Plant. I had started out going a different direction and went through a couple revisions as I learned the data set I am working with. Yesterdays comment form JamieD77 pointed out my errant ways and I quickly had it working correctly. I tried your SQL Statement this am and found after removing Plant I got the same result with or without the Having clause. Thank you for helping me.